# Wait a async operation before execute render in express using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I'm starting to use NodeJs recently and I'm trying to create a API that will get some information from web compile it and show to the user.

My question is the follow

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  https.get(pageUrl, function (res) {
     res.on('data', function (responseBuffer) {
         //Important info;
        info = responseBuffer;
     }
   }

   res.render('page', { important: info});
 }
```

How can I wait until I have the "info" var and then send the res.render. Because right now if I try to wait it usually the program ends and don't wait the result.

Thanks.

Comment: Put the `res.render` inside the `res.on` callback, right beneath the `info` assignment

Comment: @Michael, can you explain a little bit more your solution? tymeJV I did tried it, but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `https.get` call gives you a stream with an `'end'` event <sup>[1]</sup>, you can do the following:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  https.get(pageUrl, function (res) {
     var info;

     res.on('data', function (responseBuffer) {
         //Important info;
        info = responseBuffer;
     }

     res.on('end', function() {
       res.render('page', { important: info});
     })
   }
 }
```

Note that the above code will not work because you shadowed the base `res` parameter with the `res` parameter from the `https.get` callback.

Also, note that the `'data'` event may be emitted several times (again, assuming a standard stream implementation<sup>[1]</sup>), so you should accumulate the results inside your `info` variable.

<sup>[1]</sup> Could you please post more information about your code, such as where the `https` library comes from (is it the standard HTTPS lib?).

---

Personal thought: I highly suggest using the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), disponible on NPM via `npm install request`, for HTTP(S) requests to external services. It's got a neat interface, is simple to use and handles a lot of situations for you (redirects are one example, JSON and `Content-Type` another).

Comment: That's helped a lot. I did follow your advice and start to use the request library, that's was a very good idea too.